# vanilla JS localStorage persist data on refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage, data-loss

I'm using vanilla JS and I want to persist data on `localStorage` when page refreshes:

**main.js**

```
localStorage.setItem("language", "ar");

const toEnglish = (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest(".english")) {
    localStorage.setItem("language", "en");
  }
};

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => toEnglish(e));
```

however, after setting `language` to `en` on `localStorage`, if the page refreshes the value resets to `ar`, i wonder why it doesn't persist the value like in `reactJS` ?

Comment: It happen because every page load you change language to `ar`

Comment: `if(!localStorage.getItem("language")) localStorage.setItem("language", "ar")` you could set `ar` as default only if there isn't a value set already

Comment: i see, didn't actually think much about it after solving a big problem, kinda tired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happen because every page load you change language to `ar`

You need to check is language already set

```js
if (!localStorage.getItem("language")) {
  localStorage.setItem("language", "ar");
}

const toEnglish = (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest(".english")) {
    localStorage.setItem("language", "en");
  }
};

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => toEnglish(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, looks like you are setting the `language` value to `'ar'` every time the page loads, on way to work around that is by checking if localStorage has a value set for `language`, try this:

```js
const language = localStorage.getItem('language');

// check if language is not set
if (!language) {
  localStorage.setItem("language", "ar");
}

// The rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Added some extra code which might make your code work.

```
const secondaryLanguage = localStorage.getItem("language-secondary");
localStorage.setItem("language", secondaryLanguage ?? "ar");

const toEnglish = (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest(".english")) {
    localStorage.setItem("language-secondary", "en"); //change the key
  }
};

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => toEnglish(e));
```